# Dynamics AX / AXAPTA .Net Business Connector - How to clear old exceptions

Tags: exception, axapta, business-connector

I'm writing a little tool to process AX transactions and have discovered that with each error, my exception output grows.

It appears that each time an XppException happens all previous exceptions are output as well. As you can imagine, this is not pretty and can cause confusion.

Is there some way to clear all the built-up exception messages when handling each exception?

Also, I am getting a large number of

> ClrBridgeLoader : fatal error : Microsoft.Dynamics.ClrBridge.dll cannot be loaded.

error messages. How to clear these up as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out on my own:

```
AxaptaObject infolog = this._ax.GetObject("infolog");
infolog.Call("clear", 0);
```